# Visual Studio 2019 doesn't see framework higher than 3.5

Tags: .net, visual-studio, frameworks

I ran into a problem - Visual Studio doesn't want to see the Framework above the 3.5 version.

I have already installed the Developer Packs of .NET 4.5 and .NET 4.7.2 Frameworks from the official site, as well as when installing Visual Studio:

[Last framework in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0eL3.png)

[Installed components in VS installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xiGZ.png)

[Installed apps in VS installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbLNb.png)

Comment: Have you run repairs on the VS and .NET Dev Pack installs? Likely something is broken in your installs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Richard! Unfortunately, it didn't, but I completely removed DevPacks and VS... Then re-installed but nothing worked, the maximum version of the framework is 3.5(

Comment: A repair covers more ground, and should also be run on the Framework Developer Packs as well (I'm not sure which side does the registration that allows VS to see that .NET Framework version).

Comment: Unfortunately, the VIsual Studio recovery and Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool didn't help... I have a second Windows on this PC, but this is not the solution